# How many planets did the Robinsons visit?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965

In "Island in the Sky", the third episode of *Lost in Space*, the *Jupiter 2* crashes on a planet, apparently named Priplanus.  For the next few episodes, it's rather clear they have not made it back into space and reached another planet between episodes.  In the next two episodes, we find out Priplanus has an eccentric orbit, causing the weather, periodically, to go from extreme cold to extreme heat.  This is mentioned at some point later in the first season, so it's clear they were on Priplanus for most of that time.

In the first episode of the second season, "Blast Off into Space", the Robinson's leave a planet, but it's not clear if they're leaving Priplanus or if they've been on more than one planet since "Island in the Sky".  Then, several episodes later, it seems, in "Forbidden World", the *Jupiter 2* is once again stuck on a planet for most, if not all of the 2nd season, until they blast off in "Condemned of Space" (the first episode of the 3rd season).  During the third season, they have a mix of space bound and planet bound episodes.

**Overall, how many planets did the *Jupiter 2* (or the Robinsons, using the Space Pod or other means) visit?**

Is there any reason to believe that they left Priplanus during the first season and landed elsewhere, or that, after landing on a planet in the 2nd season, that they left it before "Condemned of Space"?

Comment: I'm not sure it's stated that they leave Priplanus before *Blast Off into Space* but they are pulled down to a new planet in *The Ghost Planet* but they must escape there because they are forced down to another planet in the very next episode *Forbidden World*.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Thanks - yes, I missed that.  I'll edit the question to include that.

Comment: Find a list of all 3rd season episodes by airdate. Assume that every time they blast off a planet and are seen on the ground in the next episode they have landed sometime between the episodes. Count up the 3rd season planets and add 3 for seasons 1 & 2. Then find out the order the 3rd season episodes were produced in and count all examples of blasting off in one episode and being on the ground in the next episode as examples of landing between episodes. Count up the 3rd season planets and add 3 for seasons 1 & 2 . If the numbers are different, chose the one you like best.

Comment: Here is a list of the production codes for lost in space episodes, which should correlate with their production order.  http://www.iann.net/lis/episodes/index.htm

Comment: Having re-watched only half of the first season to-date (local TV station just started airing the series daily), all episodes since the landing in "Island in the Sky" must be on the same planet since nothing on-screen so much as hints at a successful departure from it - no depictions of a takeoff or landing, nothing in dialog or on-screen action. Since several episodes show tables of hydroponic or whatever farming, and dialog suggests attempts to repair/refuel the ship in preparation for an eventual flight, I'd say it's pretty much a given that the ship hasn't flown either on or off screen.

Comment: ... as I understand it, the entire first season is set on Priplanus, the second season starts with a departure and journey to another planet where they remain for that season, and then the third season is planet-of-the-week, but I haven't yet seen for myself.

Comment: @AnthonyX: Every season starts with them in space for a bit.  I think they stay on Priplanus from when they first crash land on it, in "Island in the Sky" (S1,E3) until it breaks up and they lift off in "Blast off into Space" (S2, E1).  Then they crash again in "Forbidden World" (S2, E4) and I think that's the big landing for S2.  Then they lift off again in "Condemned of Space" (S3, E1).  There's no clarity if they visited other planets in S1 or S2.  I think, the way S1 was one, it was all on Priplanus, but it seems less clear about S2.  And, as you point out, S3 is "planet of the week."

Comment: Forgot to mention... that the attempts to repair/refuel Jupiter 2 in the episodes I've re-watched so far all get nowhere - thwarted by accidents, Dr. Smith, natural disasters, Dr. Smith, alien influence, Dr. Smith, etc.. kinda like the castaways trying to get off Gilligan's Island.

Comment: @AnthonyX: Yeah, they have had fuel problems, but I tend to write that off.  In one episode, they did pass by Earth, in "Wild Adventure" (S2, E2), but didn't have enough fuel to land, yet in the next episode they had enough fuel to land on the robot planet and take off again.  So if we take all this as canon, and not bad writing (yeah, well...), then they clearly have had adventures between episodes (even with the cliffhanger endings each episode).

Answer (score 3):

I believe they blasted off from Priplanus in the Season 2 opener.  Though there is no dialogue to support that, the rock formations around the Jupiter 2 are the same as the rock formations around it all through Season 1.

The Robinsons visited 2 planets in Season 2, the first being "The Ghost Planet" in episode 3 of Season 2 and then crash landing on "Forbidden World" in episode 4 of Season 2.

There were several planets in Season 3, which at times you'd see them leaving a planet in one episode and then the next they would already be encamped on another.  So the number of planets in Season 3 would almost be theoretical.

Comment: So how many would that be in total  The asker is really looking for a definitive answer here.

Comment: Find a list of all 3rd season episodes by airdate.  Assume that every time they blast off a planet and are seen on the ground in the next episode they have landed sometime between the episodes.  Count up the 3rd season planets and add 3 for seasons 1 & 2.  Then find out the order the 3rd season episodes were produced in and count all examples of blasting off in one episode and being on the ground in the next episode as examples of landing between episodes.  Count up the 3rd season planets and add 3 for seasons 1 & 2 .  If the numbers are different, chose the one you like best.

Comment: One small caveat is that you cannot always rely on a broadcaster showing them in the correct order moreso for such an old series. Either by accident or design it can happen.